# Dynamically change bootstrap to centre if less than 3 in a row

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I have three `col-md-4` columns displaying an image in each. If a user only has say 1 or 2 images uploaded it will float the content left as normal but leave the third with wasted space.

Is it possible with CSS to centre the 1-2 columns until a 3rd has been added?

```
    <div class="container>

     <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4 image-1">
         <img>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 image-2">
         <img>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 image-3">
         <img>
        </div>

     </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should not mix left-aligned items (when 3 or more) with center aligned items. What happens when a group of 2 items follows a group of 4 or 5?

If you want them all centered, just add a custom class (`.centerRows` in my case) to the container and use the `CSS` below:

```css
.centerRows>.row {
  text-align: center;
}
.centerRows>.row>[class^="col-"] {
  text-align: initial;
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container centerRows">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 image-1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 image-2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 image-1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 image-2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 image-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 image-1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 image-1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 image-2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 image-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 image-1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 image-2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you only want to center the rows with 2 or less children, add a custom class to the rows you want centered, after counting their children via js. Proof of concept:

```js
$('.container>.row').each(function(){
  if($(this).children().size() < 3) $(this).addClass('centerMe');
})
```

```css
.centerMe {
  text-align: center;
}
.centerMe>[class^="col-"] {
  text-align: initial;
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 image-1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 image-2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 image-1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 image-2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 image-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 image-1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 image-1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 image-2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 image-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 image-1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 image-2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay I see what you are doing here. I am wanting to only centre when less than 3 columns. There will also only ever be one row as it just displays 3 max. I may try and see if I can go the js route instead!

Comment: I've added the necessary `jQuery` for only centering the divs which have only one or two children in the second snippet. However, you should adjust the selectors to match the classes in your project. I recommend using a specific class for rows where you want to apply this.

Comment: Brilliant! i'll give that a try. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

IMHO you can't do this with css. It can be done 
using JS. Something like this:

```
if($('.image-3').length === 0){
    $('.row').find('div').RemoveClass('col-md-4');
    $('.row').find('div').AddClass('col-md-6');
}
```

But if you'll add more statement to the algorithm, i mean
"if it will be only one div, or only 4(with one on next row)"
you'll have to get more complicated code.